# DetailsView not working with selectable GridView

Tags: asp.net

My DetailsView is always blank.  I've tested both Data Sources in QueryBuilder and they return values.  I suspect something is wrong with the parameter value assignments in PoweredEquipDetails where they are set to the SelectedValue in GridView1, but I don't know why it wouldn't work.

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="PoweredEquipHeader" DataKeyNames="Model,Serial">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Model" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial" HeaderText="Serial" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Serial" />
    </Columns>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FF6600" />
  </asp:GridView>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PoweredEquipHeader" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CPECConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="Select t1.Model, t1.Serial From Powered_Equip t1 Where TechID = @TechID And Store = @Store">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="TECH01" Name="TechID" 
            QueryStringField="Tech" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0000" Name="Store" 
            QueryStringField="Store" />
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PoweredEquipDetail" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CPECConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT t1.Serial, t1.Model, t1.Status, t1.[Trailer VIN], t2.Tag, t2.State, t2.ExpMonth, t2.ExpYear FROM Powered_Equip AS t1 INNER JOIN Trailers AS t2 ON t1.[Trailer VIN] = t2.VIN WHERE (t1.Serial = @Serial) AND (t1.Model = @Model)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Serial" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Model" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="PoweredEquipDetail" DataKeyNames="Serial,Model">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial" HeaderText="Serial" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Serial" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Model" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Trailer VIN" HeaderText="Trailer VIN" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Trailer VIN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tag" HeaderText="Tag" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Tag" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="State" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpMonth" HeaderText="ExpMonth" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ExpMonth" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpYear" HeaderText="ExpYear" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ExpYear" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
</form>
```

EDIT:  So I believe what is happening is the GridView's SelectedValue in the DetailsView parameter assignments is always Model, instead of both Model and Serial as specified in my DataValueKeys.  In the event that an equipment item has a model and serial that are the same value (i.e. Model 118 Serial 118), the DetailsView populates.  But in any case where the Model and Serial are different (which will be almost every other case), the DetailsView is blank.  So how do I get two different SelectedValues to assign value to two different ControlParameters?

Comment: From GridView1 Selected Value as provided in the <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Serial" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Model" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>

Comment: I have tried changing that to String and Object before with no difference. Both Serial and Model are string values.

Comment: It is.  The items display and the rows are selectable.  When I click Select, I can see the page Post Back.  But the EmptyDataText in the DetailsView is always displayed.  Also am doing a WriteLine in GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged with GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Values[0] and [1] and the correct Model/Serial number print.  Has to be something related to type, but not sure what else to try.  Char throws a "String must be exactly one character long" exception. String and Object keep it empty.

Comment: I have tested it on my side and it is working fine. May be some think is broken in code. You can try to delete SQLDataSource and DetailView and recreate them.

Comment: I have done that twice.  Tested Chrome and IE, so not a browser issue.

Comment: Yes it should not be a browser issue.

Comment: Please see the Edit I just made to the original post.  Found a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Serial" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Model" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
```

to

```
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Serial" 
            PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Values[Serial]" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Model" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Have you find the solution or not?

Comment: Yup. This was it.  Just can't mark it as the answer until tomorrow.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = int.Parse(GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    TextBox4.Text = n.ToString();

    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAB-III-136;Initial Catalog=student;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from student1 where id='" + TextBox4.Text  + " '", con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "temp");


    DetailsView2.DataSource = ds;
    DetailsView2.DataBind();
```